# How can I add a role to a user on DiscordJS v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am having problems adding a role to a user with DiscordJS v13. Is there any way to do it? Whenever I add them, they're not defined. Here's the code to where I want to add the add role. I'm a beginner on discord.js so bear with me. Thanks!

```
    } else if (commandName === 'verification'){
        let code1 = 'A96B2UUH'
        const code = options.getString('code')

        if(code === code1){
            interaction.reply({
                content: 'The code has been accepted. Welcome to the hub!',
                ephemeral: true,
            })
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Equitability')
            message.member.roles.add(role)
        }else{
            interaction.reply({
                content: 'You entered the wrong code. Please contact the administrators to gain access.',
                ephemeral: true,
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Edit: I fixed it! I changed some things and somehow it worked. Here's the code.

```
bot.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return

    const { options } = interaction

    if(interaction.commandName === 'verification'){
        let code1 = 'A96B2UUH'
        const code = options.getString('code')

        if(code === code1){
            await interaction.reply({
                content: 'You entered the correct code. Welcome to the hub!',
                ephemeral: true,
            })
            var guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('907259574342537236')
            const member = await guild.members.fetch(interaction.user.id)
            const role = await guild.roles.fetch('907261775622328352')
            member.roles.add(role)
        }else{
            await interaction.reply({
                content: 'The code you entered is incorrect. Contact the administrators to gain access the server.',
                ephemeral: true,
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`.some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) which returns a [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) (`true`/`false`). You want the role object, so you use [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) which takes the same arguments, but returns the role object instead. Also, if the role is not cached, you can use [`RoleManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch) to get it from the API

```js
await message.guild.roles.fetch() //optional - put it if the role is valid, but is not cached
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Equitability')
message.member.roles.add(role)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I already fixed it! :)

Comment: Well if this helps, you can consider upvoting/accepting

Answer (score 1):

Getting roles in Discord.js v13 requires them to be cached, so the best way to add a role you know exists is simply by ID.

To get an ID for a role open Server Settings > Roles > Right click > "Copy ID"

Then you can simply do
`message.member.roles.add("roleId");`

If you're not completely certain whether a role exists (i.e through user input) you can fetch all server roles (different to `.cache.get`), then user `.filter`, however this doesn't seem to be what you're doing so I won't include it